# trigger to avoid child record deletion based on conditions on parent record

Tags: before-trigger, child-to-parent

child=past_information__c ,
parent=consultant__c
prevent deletion of child records were parent has type__c='employee' and status__c='approved'

my code :

```
trigger avoidDeletionPastInfo on past_information__c (before delete) {
 for (past_information__c  a : [ SELECT id FROM consultant__c where type__c='employee' 
                               and status__c='approved' and Id IN:Trigger.old]) {
       
       a.addError(
            'Cannot delete account with related opportunities.');
   }
    
}
```

error iam getting :Invalid bind expression type of past_information__c for Id field of SObject consultant__c

Comment: Is the parent to child relationship a master-detail or lookup relationship?

Comment: @compski lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating Child record  i.e is *past_information__c* but making query on Parent *consultant__c*

```
for (past_information__c  a : [ SELECT id FROM consultant__c where type__c='employee' 
                               and status__c='approved' and Id IN:Trigger.old]){}
```

for(Child__c ch: ListofChild){}

You can have your trigger similar to below

```
trigger avoidDeletionPastInfo on past_information__c  (before delete) {
 
    List < ID > parentIds = new List < ID > ();
    for (past_information__c ch: trigger.old) {
        parentIds.add(ch.consultant__c);
    }

    Map<Id, consultant__c > m = new Map<Id, consultant__c >([Select Id From consultant__c Where where type__c='employee' and status__c='approved' and Id IN:parentIds]); 
    For(past_information__c ch: trigger.old) {
        If(m.keySet().contains(ch.consultant__c))
        ch.addError('You cannot delete ');
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you @AbhinavThakur it worked.